# Java "While" Loop -- Counting Matches Algo - Assigning value must occur inside the while loop

Tags: java, while-loop

I apologize in advance; I couldn't find the answer to this simple question in Search.

I'm a newbie to coding.  Currently on Udacity working my way through the Intro to Java Programming course.

There's something that I'm not understanding as it relates certain Algorithms.

Take the "counting matches" algo for example.

The assignment of double input = in.nextDouble(); needs to occur inside the while-loop.

If I place it just above the while-loop, it breaks the program.  Why?

It seems to me that Java shouldn't care when the value is stored in the variable.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CountingMatches
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int counter = 0;

        System.out.print("Enter a value, Q to quit: ");    

        // double input = in.nextDouble(); // remember to place the assignment of this variable inside the while loop.
                                            // I tend to want to place this outside the while loop because I still don't     
                                            // understand why it necessarily must occur inside the while loop.

        while (in.hasNextDouble())
        {

            double input = in.nextDouble(); // this assignment is properly located here as opposed to just above the while-loop

            if (input < 0)
             {
                 counter++;
             }

            System.out.print("Enter a value, Q to quit: ");
        }

        System.out.println("The water line fell on " + counter + " years.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Because `in.nextDouble()` can only be used if `Scanner` has already confirmed the next token can be parsed as a double. In addition to waiting for user input, this is what `hasNextDouble()` guarantees for you. If you take it out of the loop, not only are you skipping that `hasNextDouble()` guarantee (and not giving the user a chance to input anything), you are also only running `nextDouble()` one time, so you wouldn't have the newest value anyway.

> Returns true if the next token in this scanner's input can be interpreted as a double value using the nextDouble() method. The scanner does not advance past any input.

-- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextDouble--

Comment: Did you mean `hasNextDouble()` will never be false?

Comment: @KevinEsche yeah and also considering the way `Scanner` works that answer was misleading anyway

Answer (score 0):

since you can´t do any further input when you move it outside the loop the condition for the loop `in.hasNextDouble()` will allways be true. Afterwards you will be stuck in an infinite loop, which makes the programm like like it´s brocken, but actually it´s just repetitively looping and printing until you stop the java process by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You are right that java shouldn't (and doesn't) care when the value is being stored in a variable, but there is more to it.
`in.hasNextDouble()` doesn't return until the line inside the wrapped input stream has ended.
It does not alter the stream in any way, but it guarantees there is a character sequence waiting in the stream and if true can be parsed as a double. The buffer is not altered until `nextDouble()` is called. 
This is what breaks your code. When you remove the line from the buffer without it being parseable to a double an exception is thrown, because no characters are waiting in `System.in`